# java multiple XOR

Tags: java, encryption, xor

I have 8 strings each containing 32 bit binary words (numbered from w<sub>-8</sub> to w<sub>-1</sub>)

I then need to perform XOR operations using these 8 binary words according to the formula:

w<sub>i</sub> := (w<sub>i−8</sub> ⊕ w<sub>i−5</sub> ⊕ w<sub>i−3</sub> ⊕ w<sub>i−1</sub> ⊕ φ ⊕ i) <<< 11  (i ranges from 0 to 131)

the first 4 terms are 32 bit binary words(strings)

φ = 0x9e3779b9 (hexadecimal)

I am using this for my project to create sub keys for encryption and i don't know how to perform XOR operation on 6 terms at once.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: java XOR operator is ^. Thus you need to do wi := (wi−8 ^ wi−5  ^ wi−3  ^wi−1  ^φ  ^ i) <<< 11

Comment: @akshayapandey add as an answer

Comment: @akshayapandey how will that work? because they are all strings. Additionally i is of a different length

Comment: @akshayapandey I just checked. ^ does not work for strings

Comment: XORing strings doesn't make sense, so you need to clarify your question.

Comment: @JamesKPolk the strings contain a binary number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of your requirements are unclear. Perhaps this would help demonstrate techniques you could use.

```
// I have 8 strings each containing 32 bit binary words (numbered from w-8 to w-1)
String [] strings = new String[] {
        "01000010101010100100001010101010",
        "01000010101010100100001010101010",
        "01000010101010100100001010101010",
        "01000010101010100100001010101010",
        "01000010101010100100001010101010",
        "01000010101010100100001010101010",
        "01000010101010100100001010101010",
        "01000010101010100100001010101010"
};
// Make Integers out of them.
List<Integer> ints = Arrays.stream(strings).map(s -> Integer.parseInt(s, 2)).collect(Collectors.toList());
// Reference specific ones by name.
Integer w8 = ints.get(7);
Integer w5 = ints.get(4);
Integer w3 = ints.get(2);
Integer w1 = ints.get(0);
int φ = 0x9e3779b9;


public void test(String[] args) {
    for ( int i = 0; i <= 131; i++ ) {
        int wi = (w8 ^ w5 ^ w3 ^ w1 ^ φ ^ i) << 11;
        System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(wi));
    }
}
```